# Undefined reference to constructor, generic class

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

I'm just learning template programming in C++ and have a problem with linker unable to find my class'es constructor's definition. What can be the cause? Code below.

**Logger.h**

```
template <class T>
class Logger {
public:
    Logger(NodeHandle& nh, char* topic, short pubFrequency);
    virtual ~Logger();

    void publish();
    T& getMsg();

private:
    NodeHandle& nh_;
    Publisher publisher_;
    T msg_;
    const char* topic_;
    const short pubFrequency_;
};
```

**Logger.cpp**

```
template <class T>
Logger<T>::Logger(NodeHandle& nh, char* topic, short pubFrequency) :
    nh_(nh),
    topic_(topic),
    pubFrequency_(pubFrequency),
    publisher_(topic_, static_cast<Msg*>(&msg_)) {}

template <class T>
Logger<T>::~Logger() {}
```

Then, when I'm trying to create a Logger instance in main.cpp

```
NodeHandle nh; 
Logger<std_msgs::String> logger(nh, "test", 10);
```

the linker is complaining:

```
undefined reference to `Logger<std_msgs::String>::Logger(NodeHandle&, char*, short)'
```

What am I doing wrong? There are no compiler errors, so all includes are there, I guess.

Comment: There are a million gazillion duplicates for this question; I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the templated implementation to be in the header.

Any code referencing the templated code needs to "see" the implementation so the compiler can generate the code from the template.